# Help with notation p(y|x, w, beta)

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability

In a Machine Learning course the notation used is the following:

[image]

I understand the normal (I think) on the RHS, but I can't figure out what this `p` is. Is it:

1. Conditional distribution? If yes, why are there 3 parts after the `|`. I've only seen $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ sort.
2. Parametrized distribution of the $f(x; \theta)$ type? What is $\theta$?

Also, is it $p( (y|x),   w, \beta)$? Like is it `y` given `x`? or is it `y` given all of $x, w, \beta$?

This notation is prevalent in Bishop, PRML. Here is a section where the book describes this:
[image]

I've been learning stats on my own from All of Statistics ([pdf](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~wainer/cursos/1s2013/ml/livro.pdf)), and I can't find equivalent notation (granted, I'm only on page 70).

Being a newbie to stats, I would appreciate any tips on this.

Answer (score 2):

It's conditional distribution. I find that in this area of math, authors are rather unforgiving in that there's a good handful of overlapping notations and conventions used, and you're expected to catch on.

Let's go back to the very basics and think of "events". $P(A|B)$ might help you understand something like $P(rain|cloudy)$, which would be higher than $P(rain|sunny)$. We can express $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$.

Now you can generalize. $P(A|B,C)$ is the probability that $A$ happens given we know two things, specifically we know that $B$ and $C$ happen. In the case with events it's most like an "and" operator, so $P(A|B,C) = P(A|B \cap C)$, and it's only defined if $B$ and $C$ intersect.

Your case is more like $P(x|\theta)$. This breaks the intuition with "events" because $\theta$ isn't really an event. I find it tricky to use random variables like normal variables, and instead it's easy for me to temporarily right it as $p(x|\theta = \theta_0)$, where $\theta_0$ is a constant, not a random variable. Then it's clear to me that when we "condition" with the $|$ notation it's a lot like plugging in a value, or considering what happens if we plug in a value. Therefore you read this as: "What's the probability of $x$ once we plug in some value for $\theta$"? Plugging in $\theta$ is of course knowledge you'd like to use to figure out the probability of $x$.

Now in your case, $p(x|\theta_1, \theta_2)$ means, what's the probability of $x$ if we plug in, or "know", values for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Hopefully this way of describing things makes it clearer how to hop to the case of two conditioned variables or more.

Comment: So small "p" is the conditional pdf? But if that is the case, how can RV be an event? RV is a mapping from samples space to R... so $p(t | x, w, \beta)$ where $x, w, \beta$ are random variables makes no sense to me. :-(

Comment: @drozzy firstly, so many authors use $p$ and $P$ interchangeably. I guess I see $P$ for discrete case a little more often but you can't rely on the difference between $p$ and $P$ to tell you what the author means.

Comment: @drozzy usually $p$ is pdf in the continuous case. And the continuous case isn't really about "events." When I'm in the continuous case I do frequently try to understand how the discrete case works, but when you go back to the continuous case you have to remember that continuous RVs don't represent "events" anymore.

Comment: @drozzy maybe you want to review how to condition on a continuous variable in the first place. I'm not sure that it's the fact that you're conditioning on multiple continuous RVs, that's confusing you. One or multiple RVs conditioned on doesn't really make much difference intuitively.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I just thought that pdfs can only be bivariate. Just saw this in the stats book (I probably forgot it completely): "Let $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ denote the pdf. It is possible to define their marginals, conditionals etc. much the same way as in the bivariate case." So I guess $p(x | blah, blah, blah)$ is just a multivariate conditional distribution, that can be expanded by Bayes' rule (as in the case of events).

Comment: Or not Bayes', but just like conditional definition: $p_{1...q | q+1 ... k} (x_1, ... x_q | x_{q+1} ... x_k } = p(x_1, ..., x_k) / p_{q+1 ... k} (x_{q+1}, .., x_k)$ Source: p7: https://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/sR-7.pdf

Comment: One more question: Is $\beta$ also a RV?

Comment: @drozzy stats is a very multivariate field. Would you want to predict heart disease, or anything else, on just one variable? For your last question, if it's conditioned on, it would technically be an RV, but intuitively you just condition on any "unknowns." Some of those unknowns you'll do Bayes rule on or study their distributions, others are basically glorified constants. I think in this case all the math and intuition is exactly the same if you say beta is a constant, or if you say beta is a RV whose distribution we don't know.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think this is right. I think this `p` is a $p(y|x; w, \beta)$ - that is a parametrized distribution by $w, \beta$.

Comment: @drozzy I think this is more connotation... x, w, beta all play the same role, it's just emphasized that x is the data or features and w and beta are the parameters. You can condition, use Bayes' rule, etc. on any of them but the author is just trying to clarify that they're treating x as the data and w, beta as the parameters.